# sending ICMPv6 ping request

Tags: scheme, racket

How to send a ICMPv6 ping request with Racket or Scheme?

There is https://docs.racket-lang.org/net/index.html, but it has almost nothing about the internet level protocols.

There is https://docs.racket-lang.org/net2/index.html, but it seems unfinished or abandoned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Racket supplies functions to work with the **transport** layer protocols TCP and UDP on all the platforms Racket supports (e.g. *nix, macOS, Windows).

But as far as I know it does not for lower **network** layer functionality such as ICMP (for IPv4 or IPv6).

Racket does supply an FFI, through which you could call the appropriate OS-specific functions that might let you do this. However, depending on what you want to accomplish, it might be simpler to use [`process`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/subprocess.html#(def._((lib._racket%2Fsystem..rkt)._process))) to run a command like `ping` -- then `read-line` the Racket input port piped from the subprocess standard output, and parse that to get the information you need.  (If you have questions about the details of using `process`, that would probably make for a good, separate question to post here.)

---

Update: Instead of `process` you could probably just use `system`:

```rkt
#lang racket/base

(require racket/port
         racket/system)

(with-output-to-string
  (lambda () (system "ping -c 1 127.0.0.1")))
```

That returns a string like:

```
"PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes\n64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.068 ms\n\n--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---\n1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0.0% packet loss\nround-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.068/0.068/0.068/0.000 ms\n"
```